# Isomorphic Redux React boilerplate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, isomorphic-javascript

I am fairly ok with JavaScript knowledge. We are planning to start isomorphic web application using React, Redux, es6 etc. We have lot of API calls to integrate. Before starting I want to know if there are any boilerplates available or it is better to setup up everything step by step.

I just need some direction. We have lot of SEO value, doing isomorphic is compulsory.

Comment: Have you seen erikras' example? https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example

Comment: @pwagner, Thanks i will go through that example

Comment: @pwagner, example is really nice and looks like the took the real production example. you pointed to me at really good article.

Comment: You're welcome! I think it is one of the best examples with lots of followers

Comment: yeah, i went through lot of example and don't know which one to follow, i will follow this.

Comment: @pwagner initially you gave me this one right? which one is better? https://github.com/WebbyLab/itsquiz-wall

Comment: @pwagner, how is the below code calling load() action @asyncConnect([{
  deferred: true,
  promise: ({store: {dispatch, getState}}) => {
    if (!isLoaded(getState())) {
      return dispatch(loadWidgets());
    }
  }
}])

Answer (score 1):

I had your requirements and I searched for proper boilerplate, the best one that I found was [react-redux-universal-hot-example](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example). I've used it for a production.

**Advantages**

- Configure React-Router for server rendering
- Configure AsyncConnect for server rendering for API call
- Clear way to call APIs
- Clear configuration for production and development environment
- Uses `redux-form`
- Proxy API calls to main back-end server
- Configure Hot reloading
- ...

**Disadvantages**

- Build and rebuild are slow
- Prevent learning react configuration :) everything is ready

Comment: does this has hydration and dehydration for client to pick up? what does this use for api calls?

Comment: do you know what does this mean     "start": "NODE_ENV=production NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:./shared node --harmony .", does this mean go to node path and then execute the index js under shared folder? what does harmony means?

Comment: how is this code calling load() action event? @asyncConnect([{
  deferred: true,
  promise: ({store: {dispatch, getState}}) => {
    if (!isLoaded(getState())) {
      return dispatch(loadWidgets());
    }
  }
}])

Comment: @kobe: 1. This project uses some kind of [asynchronous action dispatch](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) and custom middleware for API call.

Comment: 2. `NODE_ENV=production` and other assignments are environment variables and they are used inside of project. For example by checking value of `NODE_ENV` you can do some works in non-production mode.

Comment: 3. `asyncConnect` is used for calling APIs synchronously in server-side and asynchronously in client-side (very short description I know).

Comment: what are you using in your project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121015/discussion-between-ali-sepehri-kh-and-kobe).

Answer (score 0):

If you are interesting in .NetCore as backend, there is very good boilerplate JavaScriptServices

You can generate project for VisulaStuido, using TypeScript, React, Redux, Router, server side rendering, webpack,Hot module replacement and .Net core as backend.

This is really good starting point to learn all this technologies.

https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices

Answer (score 0):

I built a website for [TechJob](https://www.techjob.co.il/) (a high-tech placement company) using [react-redux-universal-hot-example](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example) boilerplate.
It is a very good boilerplate.

It's true that you really have to go deeper into the code to understand, but it's worth it.